# Memory issue. How to identify the root cause using free

Tags: ram

I am running two application on my system.

When I run two applications in parallel, Memory gets consumed within a few minutes..

[Data below is not actual.. Just for explanation]

**Initial state..**

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3926       1193       2732          0         64        626
-/+ buffers/cache:        502       3423
Swap:         3990          0       3990
```

**Memory full state**

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3926       1193        732          0         64       2626
-/+ buffers/cache:        502       3423
Swap:         3990          0       3990
```

My first question :-

1) At this state, my screen hangs and gives out of memory error. But from understanding, it still has 3423MB of free memory to use.. Can anyone give any hints why I might get this error ??

To find which program is the culprit, I tried kill the program one by one.

When I kill program1, it frees up 100MB of cache memory and moves it to free memory..

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3926       1193        832          0         64       2526
-/+ buffers/cache:        502       3423
Swap:         3990          0       3990
```

But when I kill program2, it frees up remaining 1900MB of cache memory.. It becomes something like this

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3926       1193       2732          0         64       626
-/+ buffers/cache:        502       3423
Swap:         3990          0       3990
```

Question 2 :-

Is program2 hogging up the resources more than program1.. Is cache memory usage indicate that it is using more memory ??